# WhatsApp Read Receipt

Tags: root-access, whatsapp-messenger

How can I only partially disable read receipts on WhatsApp?
(ie. I should be able to see when others read my messages, but not have others know when I read theirs)

I have tried the script on https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/script-disable-whatsapp-read-receipts-t2933467, but there is no effect.
(Both parties can see when a message has been read)

The device in question has root access.

Comment: The link you added is pretty old! 3 years, thay may have patched that

Answer (score 0):

You are asking something impossible here (at least at my knowledge).

If you disable **Read receipt** or  **Last seen**, you won't be able to see other Receipt or Last seen.

Staying incognito while being able to see other activities is not possible using WhatsApp​. You'll need a clone WhatsApp​ to be able to do that, may be.

[image]

Comment: OP could still pull the unencrypted WhatsApp database and manually read through it. It's uncomfortable, but not impossible.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it

Comment: I mean that, due to the asker having root privileges, they can dump WhatsApp's messages database (which is an unencrypted SQL database) from the app's appropriate directory under **/data/data/com.whatsapp**, and then proceed to read this database with tools such as `sqlite3`, without WhatsApp knowing anything.

Comment: That's not what OP is trying to do! Did you understand his question? Or do you mean they have to read the message straight to the database instead of in app during a chat session?

Comment: In fact, it's *half* of what OP is trying to do: to read a message without others knowing. If there would be a solution outside of Lucky Patcher, I would've written an *answer*, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, it worth to be mentioned... really uncomfortable thought